# Manage multiple database IDs across environments

Tags: database, asp.net-core, environment

At work we have different databases for production and development environments. Those databases have the same schema, but the data is quite different.

We have multiple "behavior variables" which, in the backend, lead to code like this

```
switch(row.ProcessID)
{
    case 1:
        buy();
        break;
    case 2:
        sell();
        break;
}
```

The problem here, of course, is the same code for production should, for example, look like this

```
switch(row.ProcessID)
{
    case 2:
        buy();
        break;
    case 8:
        sell();
        break;
}
```

The question is how can I handle those IDs different in development and production?

Answer (score 0):

You could inject `IWebHostEnvironment` to use `IsDevelopment()` and `IsProduction()` extension to meet your requirement:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        switch (row.ProcessID)
        {
            case 1:
                buy();
                break;

            case 2:
                if (_env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    sell();
                }
                else
                {
                    buy();
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                sell();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you use asp.net core 2.x,you need use `IHostingEnvironment`.

Comment: The problem with this is the code would be duplicated, with those IDs being the only difference